# Get Value from another div, subtract, and populate another div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the value of one specific div class, subtract that by 500 and then populate the result into another div.

I'm not quite sure what process I would need in order to populate the result of the subtraction into the other div.

Something like this:

```
<div class="main-value">5000</div>
<!-- main-value - 500-->
<div class="new-value"></div>

//Script
var main  = $(".main-value");
main.html(parseInt(main.html()) - 500 ).appendTo($(".new-value"));
```

So far, the subtraction work, but I can't get it to append the updated value to the empty div and keep the original one intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, you need to clone the element otherwise it may update and append the original element. Although parsing the string is optional since the operation is subtraction.

```js
var main = $(".main-value");
main.clone().text(main.text() - 500).appendTo($(".new-value"));
//----^^^^----- clone the element
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-value">5000</div>
<!-- main-value - 500-->
<div class="new-value"></div>
```

---

In case you just want to show the result in `new-value` class then do it like.

```js
var main = $(".main-value");
// update the text content in `new-value` div
$(".new-value").text(main.html() - 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-value">5000</div>
<!-- main-value - 500-->
<div class="new-value"></div>
```

Comment: I was _just_ going down the clone route, and this totally works. Thanks for helping me organize my logic!

Comment: @ultraloveninja : glad to help :)

Comment: Is there a source that performing calculations with the results of jQuery.text updates/appends the original element?  That seems like really bad behavior to me

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var mainval  = $(".main-value").text();
$(".new-value").text(parseInt(mainval) - 500);
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 0):

Break it into two:

```
var main = $(".main-value");
mainValue = parseInt(main.html());
$(".new-value").html(mainValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>

<div class="main-value">5000</div>
<div class="new-value">  </div>

<script>
var x= document.getElementsByClassName("main-value")[0].innerHTML;
var y= document.getElementsByClassName("new-value")[0];
y.innerHTML= x-500;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is without jquery

Comment: This snippet has an incorrect document type (doctype).